# Jekyll issues after updating Mac to Sierra, could not find 'jekyll' Gem load error.?

Tags: macos, jekyll

I seem to be having issues with jekyll after updating my mac from El Capitan to Sierra. If I check the version of jekyll, the following is returned.

```
Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0) among 17 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError).
```

However, if I gem update jekyll, it says it there is nothing to update. I've googled for quite some time and hope someone has some suggestions. I'm still very new to coding. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a `Gemfile` in your working directory? Chances are, your project expects to have Bundler be running and configured. Maybe this is broken.

To try out, you can do the following:

1. `gem install bundler`
2. `bundle install`
3. `bundle exec jekyll build`

1) installs the bundler gem, if it's not available.
2) Installs all the dependencies for your project, hopefully also the necessary Jekyll version.
3) This command builds your website with the Jekyll version installed by Bundler.

Comment: Thank you so much! Number one worked. gem installed. However it seems I am unable to install dependencies. I'm not sure if these issues are related.

Comment: I think you should open a second question for that. Pleas post gemfile and config so people can see if there is an issue

Comment: I see you are new to SOF, so just saying you can upvote or accept answers if you see fit! Cheers